# How to Fix Failed to launch Pixel 2 API 29: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds error on Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm new to flutter/andrdroid studio, I flollowed the guide on flutter.dev, and i'm still not able to get the sample project to run.

I have gone through several blog posts even here on stackoverflow and still cant get a solution.

Below are the details of my setup.

```
Android Studio Version  3.5;
VSCode Version          1.38.1;
SDK Platform-tools      Android 10.0(Q) API Level 29;
OS                      Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS;
adb version             1.0.41;
CPU                     Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz;
```

**Error Message on VSCode :** `Failed to launch Pixel 2 API 29: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds`

**Error on Android Studio :** `No Error Message, Selecting the device from the device drop-down starts the emulator, but does not connect. <no devices> is still selected.`

I have upgraded the adb platform-tools, I have created different devices on Android studio,using the Tools/AVD menu
I have seleced wipe data, under AVD manager after closing the emulator
Changed the quickboot option, to cold boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Genymotion Emulator and Launch it first before running your app.
I did it and it helped me.

Comment: I would try this and share feedback. Thank you.